# Outlook 2016, Large .ost File after Deleting All Emails and Compacting

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016

I upgraded to the MS Outlook 2016 client on my PC. I use it with a gmail account.

When I added the account, it creates a new `.ost` file, and it imported all of my emails since 2006. This grew the `.ost` file to over 1gb.

Since I already have those old emails in a previous `.pst` file, I just deleted them all from the `.ost`. Once everything is deleted, and trash emptied, etc. I compacted the `.ost` file from within the Outlook file management area, however, it didn't really clear out much space at all.

What am I missing?

I don't want to delete and re-create the `.ost` file as many suggest on various support forums, etc... because I think it would cause outlook to re-import all of those emails again.

How can I re-claim this space?